# How to check for intersection of two DataFrame columns in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, sparkr

Using either `pyspark` or `sparkr` (preferably both), how can I get the intersection of two `DataFrame` columns? For example, in `sparkr` I have the following `DataFrames`:

```
newHires <- data.frame(name = c("Thomas", "George", "George", "John"),
                       surname = c("Smith", "Williams", "Brown", "Taylor"))
salesTeam <- data.frame(name = c("Lucas", "Bill", "George"),
                        surname = c("Martin", "Clark", "Williams"))
newHiresDF <- createDataFrame(newHires)
salesTeamDF <- createDataFrame(salesTeam)

#Intersect works for the entire DataFrames
newSalesHire <- intersect(newHiresDF, salesTeamDF)
head(newSalesHire)

        name  surname
    1 George Williams

#Intersect does not work for single columns
newSalesHire <- intersect(newHiresDF$name, salesTeamDF$name)
head(newSalesHire)
```

> Error in as.vector(y) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a
>   vector

How can I get `intersect` to work for single columns?

Comment: working fine in pyspark
`spark.createDataFrame(["a","b","x"],StringType()).intersect(spark.createDataFrame(["z","y","x"],StringType()))`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need two Spark DataFrames to make use of the intersect function. You can use select function to get specific columns from each DataFrame.

In SparkR:

```
newSalesHire <- intersect(select(newHiresDF, 'name'), select(salesTeamDF,'name'))
```

In pyspark:

```
newSalesHire = newHiresDF.select('name').intersect(salesTeamDF.select('name'))
```