# Pyspark intersection of two dataframe columns

Tags: pyspark, intersection

I have two dataframes in the following format:

one is single row:

```
+-----+--------------------+                                                    
| col1|                col2|
+-----+--------------------+
|  A  |      [B, C, D]     |
+-----+--------------------+
```

The other one has multiple rows:

```
+----------+--------------------+                                               
|      col1|                col2|
+----------+--------------------+
|     F    |[A, B, C]           |
|     G    |[J, K, B]           |
|     H    |[C, H, D]           |
+----------+--------------------+
```

I am looking for the intersection of these two:

```
+----------+--------------------+                                               
|      col1|                col2|
+----------+--------------------+
|     F    |[B, C]              |
|     G    |[B]                 |
|     H    |[C, D]              |
+----------+--------------------+
```

I tried the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44168379/how-to-check-for-intersection-of-two-dataframe-columns-in-spark) but it didn't help. Is there any efficient way to find the intersection between one row dataframe and multiple rows dataframe?

Comment: You can use `explode` on `col2` in both 2 dataframe first, then use `leftsemi join` to see which data in 2nd dataframe also exist in the 1st dataframe, then `groupby` and `collect_set` the value.

Comment: A better solution is to do the `crossJoin` of two dataframe and use `array_intersect` if your spark version >= 2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

You can `crossJoin` the `col2` from the single row dataframe and use `array_intersect` function for the required intersection.

```
data2_sdf. \
    crossJoin(func.broadcast(data1_sdf.selectExpr('col2 as col_to_check'))). \
    withColumn('reqd_intersect', func.array_intersect('col2', 'col_to_check')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +----+---------+------------+--------------+
# |col1|col2     |col_to_check|reqd_intersect|
# +----+---------+------------+--------------+
# |F   |[A, B, C]|[B, C, D]   |[B, C]        |
# |G   |[J, K, B]|[B, C, D]   |[B]           |
# |H   |[C, H, D]|[B, C, D]   |[C, D]        |
# +----+---------+------------+--------------+
```